# Want to show allowed payment methods on checkout page of OpenCart

Tags: paypal, module, opencart

Hey StackOverflow Experts !

I want to show allowed payment methods on checkout page (OpenCart) according to the selected currency by visitor.

Example:

Show Ccavenue payment method if the selected currency is INR. Like PayPal payment module does it - shows if the selected currency is USD. Exactly the same I want in my Ccavenue module.

So how can I do it?

Any suggestion or solution would by appreciated.

Comment: Asked 40 Mins Ago Got 0 Replies. Disappointed !! :(

Answer (score 0):

create file & class in `catalog\model\payment\` e.g ccavenue.php or wht your requirements 
then create function as shown below hope it helps

```
public function your_function() {

     $currencies = array(
            'INR'

        );

        if (!in_array(strtoupper($this->currency->getCode()), $currencies)) {
            $status = false;
        }

           $method_data = array();

    if ($status) {  
        $method_data = array(
            'code'       => 'your_pg',
            'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
            'sort_order' => $this->config->get('your_pg_sort_order')
        );
    }

    return $method_data;
}
```

you can put different currency in  array e.g AUD etc